# Guardar formulario en Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Hola estoy creando un proyecto para el instituto, consiste en una pequeña pagina con panel de administración y elegí Django para realizar el proyecto
Mi problema es que en la pagina donde se muestra los detalles de una carrera quiero que los estudiantes o los usuarios registrados puedan dejar un comentario pero esos comentarios no se me validan 
Este es el template de el detalle de una carrera

```
`<form class="col s12" method="POST" action="{% url 'create_comment' %}"> {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
       <div class="input-field col s12">
         <textarea class="materialize-textarea" name="{{ comment_form.content }}"></textarea>
         <input type="hidden" name="{{ comment_form.carrer.title }}" value="{{ carrer.id }}">
       <label>Message</label>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-book">
     </div>
   </div>
</form>`
```

Este es el código del modelo del formulario en cuestión

```
class Comment(ITSModel):
content = models.TextField()
author = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='comments',
)
carrer = models.ForeignKey(
    Carrer,
    related_name='comments',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
)

def __str__(self):
    return self.content[:23]
```

Este es el codigo del form.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = ['content', 'carrer']
```

Este es el código del views.py`

```
def create_comment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.save()
        return redirect(comment.carrer.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Algo salio mal')`
```

Comment: ¿Cúal es la validación que quieres hacer?

Comment: Por ahora lo que veo es que tienes que corregir los nombres de los inputs, por ejemplo: `{{ comment_form.content }}` aquí estás haciendo referencia a un objeto, para acceder al nombre tendrías que hacerlo así: `{{ comment_form.content.name }}` o mucho mejor es hacerlo desde django y no poner tu componente de `textarea` si no reemplazar eso solo por esto: `{{ comment_form.content }}` y lo mismo para el otro campo que tienes

Comment: Tienes mucha razón no me había percatado de eso gracias, todo corre al 100 XD